# initializtion class object error using ternary operator

Tags: c++, constructor, ternary-operator

I'm trying to create an object using the ternary operator, But every time, its called only the first one. Here is my simple code:

```
bool itTrue(int x, int y){
  if(x>y)
     return true;
  return false;
}
class myClass {
    public:
       myClass(int x){
          val=x;
      }
       myClass(int x, int y){
          val=x*y;
      }
      val=0;
 };
int main(){
   aa=5;
   bb=6;
   myClass cc = isTrue(aa,bb) ? (aa,bb) : (bb,bb);
   cout<<cc.val<<endl;
   return 0;
}
```

Some how, using the Debuger, after isTrue functions is called, the constructor who gets called is the one using one object:
`myClass(int x)`
 But I want to use both arguments, How do I call the other one:
`myClass(int x, int y)` using the ternary operator?

Comment: You're about to get to know the comma operator. And what's "short if"?

Comment: Provide an appropriate copy constructor and write `myClass cc = isTrue(aa,bb) ? myClass(aa,bb) : myClass (bb,bb);`

Comment: Should I ignore copy constructor and just write as you said? Or do I have to implement it?

Comment: @raptor0102 it's called "ternary operator" not "short if".

Comment: Its working! Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before you try and answer the whole of your own question, we should look at what happens when we simplify it to not include the ternary operator:

```
myClass cc = (aa, bb);
```

This would also call the single-parameter constructor, because this is not how you pass parameters to a constructor, it is not the same as

```
myClass cc(aa, bb);
```

Instead, what you are doing is invoking the "comma operator". You should take a look at what value is being passed to your single value constructor, you'll find that it is the value of `bb`.

```
#include <iostream>

class A {
public:
    A(int a) {
        std::cout << "single " << a << '\n';
    }
    A(int a, int b) {
        std::cout << "double " << a << ',' << b << '\n';
    }
};

int main()
{
    int aa = 5;
    int bb = 6;

    A a = (aa, bb);
}
```

http://ideone.com/wapbv9

The comma operator evaluates the expression on the left, discards it and evaluates the expression on the right. So what you are actually writing is:

```
(void)aa;  // a way to say "evaluate this and ignore it"
A a = bb;
```

In order to do what you are trying to achieve you'll need to construct an instance of your class:

```
myClass cc = isTrue(aa, bb) ? myClass(aa, bb) : myClass(bb, bb);
```